# Invalid constructor arguments provided for a deployed Remix contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to publish a contract code on bscscan but it's showing the following error. Can someone explain what this means and how to fix it? None of the constructors have any arguments ... I don't understand this error.

```
Error! Invalid constructor arguments provided. Please verify that they are in ABI-encoded format
```

Contract code:

https://pastebin.com/sgfyQg5K

Answer (score 0):

You have to give what constructor needs on deploy. For example if constructor wants 2 uint variables then you have to give them on deploying.

Comment: I got it working. Don't know what was wrong ... erased all spaces at end of contract ... Don't have too much exp with Solidity and contracts to know what fixed it exactly.